# Angular 2 typescript error on subscribe (data.word <--- error)

Tags: angular, typescript

How to overcome this typings error I get after doing http subscribe :

```
 getPerfectObj() {
    this.object.getObjectsJson().subscribe
    (data => {
      this.jsonObj = data.obs.perfect;
    });
  }
```

`data.obs.perfect` - throws error on `obs` -

> "Property obs does not exist in type Object"

. Everything works, but when I relaunch my localhost - start my app with ng serve again it throws errors on these places.

Comment: just check the property obs is available in data by console.log(data)

Comment: It works as I said, its not error from logic, more likely its typescript error

Comment: then you can follow Artyom answer. If you have specific type , you can specify like ((data:YourObject) instead of 'any' and create a property obs in side the class

Comment: Or just go with data['obs']['perfect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 getPerfectObj() {
    this.object.getObjectsJson().subscribe
    ((data: any) => {
      this.jsonObj = data.obs.perfect;
    });
  }
```

add type `any`(or create special interface for your data object) to avoid this issue, because here lint is thinking that `data` type is `Object` and can't find obs property there